# Wrapping a switch statement in a neat loop in Java

Tags: java

I have the following code that takes 2 strings as inputs and returns Boolean on whether they're anagrams:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AnagramChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print ("Enter string 1: ");
        String str1 = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print ("Enter string 2: ");
        String str2 = sc.nextLine();

        boolean check = isAnagram (str1, str2);
        System.out.println ("Anagram check for '" + str1 + "' and '" + str2 + "': " + check);
        sc.close();
    }
    public static boolean isAnagram (String s1, String s2) {
        if(s1.length() != s2.length())
            return false;
        s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
        s2 = s2.toLowerCase();
        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < s2.length() ; i++ ){
            myList.add(String.valueOf(s2.charAt(i)));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < s1.length();i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < myList.size(); j++){
                if(myList.get(j).equals(String.valueOf(s1.charAt(i)))){

                        myList.remove(j);
                        j = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return myList.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

It is somewhat limited though, I'm trying to expand it to work for the following cases:
- different cases i.e. `eager == AGREE`
- single word with whitespaces i.e. `eager == a g ree`
- different amounts of whitespace i.e. `"  eager" == agree`

Is there a nice and clean way to integrate this into already written code above without much pain and re-writing. Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to handle them differently or just remove every whitespace and convert the strings to lowercase?

Comment: You already handle mixed-case. You could just remove all the spaces.

Comment: being able to compare the strings no matter how many spaces and no matter where they are (in front on/in the middle/after the string) is what I originally had in mind

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. Regex to the rescue! You can use the String built in .replaceAll(). Passing it the \s value will remove all spaces and characters not printed such as \n. I would suggest that during comparison you use something like the following:

```
string1.replaceAll("\\s","").equals(string2.replaceAll("\\s",""));
```

Comment: Tom, I should have made that more clear I suppose. I'll change it. I meant that more as a general "strip them of whitespace and compare" not a "never use .equals() so you can compare object values and not the strings themselves!" My fault.

Comment: What you've meant with your post explaining regex is very clear, but since I really value examples, I check if they are actually going to work. Due to that simple mistake OP could have thought, that one of the `replaceAll` calls might be wrong. Good you've fixed it :).

Comment: Tom, completely agree! I think op's example of eager == AGREE is what made my mind go down the rabbit hole of poor form. I appreciate you catching it for me!

Answer (score 1):

personally I would do the following

- use [trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) to remove leading and traiing whitespace
- use [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) to remove whitespaces
- use [toLowerCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase())() to make the text lower case
- [convert](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) the Strings into an array list of characters
- [sort the arrays](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_sort_char.htm)
- compare the arrays - if they are the same then you have an anagram

Comment: Why do you still want to use 'trim' if you already plan to use ' replace'?

Comment: trim would also remove any special characters as well. i'd do it for completeness :) but you are right it is not strictly necessary